# Error reading Cassandra TTL and WRITETIME with Spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

Although the latest spark-cassandra-connector from DataStax [states](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md) it supports reading/writing TTL and WRITETIME I am still receiving a SQL undefined function error.

Using Databricks with library com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12:3.1.0 and a Spark Config for CassandraSparkExtensions on a 9.1 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12) Cluster. CQL version 3.4.5.

```
spark.sql.extensions com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions
```

Confirmed the config with Notebook code:

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.extensions")
```

Out[7]: 'com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions'

```
# Cassandra connection configs using Data Source API V2
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.1.4.4")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.auth.username", dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "myScope", key = "CassUsername"))
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.auth.password", dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "myScope", key = "CassPassword")) 
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.enabled", True)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path", "/dbfs/user/client-truststore.jks")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password", dbutils.secrets.get("key-vault-secrets", "cassTrustPassword"))
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.spark.dse.continuous_paging_enabled", False) 

# catalog name will be "cassandrauat" for Cassandra
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat", "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cassandrauat.prop", "key")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "cassandrauat") # will override Spark to use Cassandra for all databases
```

```
%sql 
select id, did, ts, val, ttl(val) 
from cassandrauat.myKeyspace.myTable
```

**Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ttl'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 25**

When running this same CQL query on the Cassandra cluster directly it produces a result.

Any help with why the CassandraSparkExtensions aren't loading appreciated.

Adding full stack trace for NoSuchMethodError that occured after pre-loading library

```
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(Lscala/PartialFunction;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/LogicalPlan;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraMetaDataRule$.replaceMetadata(CassandraMetadataFunctions.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraMetaDataRule$$anonfun$apply$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(CassandraMetadataFunctions.scala:187)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foldLeft(Stream.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraMetaDataRule$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(CassandraMetadataFunctions.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraMetaDataRule$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(CassandraMetadataFunctions.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:428)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraMetaDataRule$.apply(CassandraMetadataFunctions.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraMetaDataRule$.apply(CassandraMetadataFunctions.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$3(RuleExecutor.scala:221)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:221)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:96)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:684)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:694)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.$anonfun$executeSql$1(SQLDriverLocal.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:298)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:37)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:518)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.executeSql(SQLDriverLocal.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SQLDriverLocal.repl(SQLDriverLocal.scala:144)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$13(DriverLocal.scala:541)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:266)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:261)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:305)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:297)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:518)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:689)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:681)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:522)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:427)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:370)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:221)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just added Spark Cassandra Connector via Clusters UI, then it will not work - the reason for that is libraries are installed into cluster after Spark already started, so class specified in `spark.sql.extensions` isn't found.

To fix this you need to put Jar file to cluster nodes before Spark starts - you can do it using the [cluster init script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts) that will either download jar directly with something like this (but it will download multiple copies - for each node):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

wget -q -O /databricks/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar \
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12/3.1.0/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar
```

or it's better to download assembly jar, put onto DBFS, and then copy from DBFS into destination directory (for example, if it's uploaded to `/FileStore/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cp /dbfs/FileStore/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar \
  /databricks/jars/
```

Update (13.11.2021): SCC 3.1.0 isn't fully compatible with Spark 3.2.0 (parts of it are already in DBR 9.1). See [SPARKC-670](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-670) for more details.

Comment: Now I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError. Could this be because I am using a Spark 3.1.2 cluster with the 3.1.0 jar? The only option I see with Azure Databricks to get a match is going all the way back to Databricks 7.3LTS, which isn't really an option for me. The driver is working for selects that don't include ttl or writetime.

Comment: Can you post stack trace?

Comment: Please put stacktrace into your question, not into the answer

Comment: see update to the answer

Comment: You can try with this build: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jx8i5i7aw42bv5k/com.datastax.spark_spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.2.0.jar?dl=0

Comment: That worked. This has been an issue for me for a while, where I could write TTL but not read it back without turning to CQL. Specifically what I did based on your solution was `dbfs cp spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.2.0.jar dbfs:/FileStore/jars/maven/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.2.0.jar`, `dbfs cp .\sparkcassandraconnector.sh dbfs:/databricks/datastax/sparkcassandraconnector.sh` then configure cluster to Databricks 10.1ML with the above init script and removed jar library from UI "Libraries".